# データグリッドに入力された内容は、Spring MVCで受け取れない？

Tags: java, spring

ヘッダ + データグリッドからなる画面を、Spring MVCで作っています。
しかし、どうしてもデータグリッドに入力された内容を受け取ることが出来ません。

こんな感じのコードを書きました

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateList")
public ModelAndView updateList(Condition condition, Grid[] grid) {
```

Spring MVCはデータグリッドに入力された内容を、受け取ることができるのでしょうか？
かれこれ、2日ほど調べてみたのですが、どうしてもわからずorz

画面イメージ
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

エラー内容

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate
>   [[Ljp.co.test.server.arrival.form.WEB_AR_INP_010_Form$Grid;]: 
>   No default constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   [Ljp.co.test.server.arrival.form.WEB_AR_INP_010_Form$Grid;.()
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     jp.co.test.server.framework.WebFilter.exec(WebFilter.java:79)
>     jp.co.test.server.framework.WebFilter.doFilter(WebFilter.java:74)

例外に表示されている「L.jp.co.test」のLって、どこから来たんでしょうか？
そもそも根本的なところで何か間違えているから、Springが「L」を付けたような気がするんです。

Comment: `Grid`は自作クラスですか？メッセージはクラス`Grid`にデフォルトコンストラクタが無いと言っていますね。

Comment: いろいろやってるうちに、自己解決しました

Comment: 問題の原因と解決方法を追加していただけると助かります。

Answer (score 2):

メソッドの引数を2つにしたのがエラーの原因だったようです。
1つのBeanにまとめたらば、エラーが発生しませんでした。

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateList")    
public ModelAndView updateList(Condition condition) throws IOException {
```

---

```
@Data
public class Condition implements Serializable {
    private String remaks;
    private List<Grid> grid;
}

@Data
public class Grid implements Serializable {
    private Integer rowNo;
    private String prodCode;
}
```

それと、Gridを自作したのですが、inputのid/nameを次のように設定しました。

```
   <input type="text" id="grid[0].prodCode" name="grid[0].prodCode">
   <input type="text" id="grid[1].prodCode" name="grid[1].prodCode">
   <input type="text" id="grid[2].prodCode" name="grid[2].prodCode">
```

やったのはこれだけです。